# How to get pressure distribution over a surface in ABAQUS?

Tags: abaqus

I'm modeling a deformable rectangular storage tank filled with water in ABAQUS.and I need to get the water pressure distribution over the long side wall at a moment.
the problem is I can't use stress output because the tank has the stresses of its own (due its weight and deformability).please help me...

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: you might try engineering.stackexchange.com, there are at least a few general abaqus questions asked over there.